# Use of "Being" in these sentence

Tags: grammar, being

Which of the following sentences are correct

1. I found the man lying on floor  with his hand tied with rope.
2. I found the man lying on floor  with his hand being tied with rope.
3. I found the man lying on floor  with a rope tied around his neck.
4. I found the man lying on floor  with a rope being tied around his neck .

Comment: 'Tied' is the past perfect tense. The act had been completed. When 'found' the person had already been tied up. 'Being tied' is the past continuous tense. When 'found' (in the past) an activity was occurring. Someone was in the process of tying, when the reported scene was initially viewed.

Comment: If I found  the man whose hand was  already been tied with rope. Can we say I found the man lying on floor with his hand being tied with rope.

Comment: No - Nigel and I have both explained that you can't. That sentence means that you witnessed him being tied up.

Comment: 'The man struggled, his hands being tied with rope' is correct. This describes a situation where someone had already tied the man up in the past. Now, being tied, he struggles. There is the question of avoiding ambiguity between the two situations : a past activity and a present effect.

Comment: They’re all grammatical, but we wouldn’t know what state you found the man in, so we can’t say which is “correct”.

Comment: They're all ungrammatical, because _lying on floor_ is ungrammatical. You can't just get one thing right in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Using *being* implies that someone was in the act of tying him up.

We say 'lying on *the* floor', and presumably the man would have both his hands tied together!

Comment: If I found the man whose hand was already been tied with rope. Can we say I found the man lying on floor with his hand being tied with rope....Kate sir pls answer my question

Comment: If the captor is currently tying the man, you could say **with his hand being tied**. However if the man is tied and the captor has left, you could say **with his hand having been tied with rope**, although this suggests that his hand is no longer tied and he has begun his escape.

Comment: See my comment above. The man is lying on _the_ floor with his _hands_ tied (unless he has been tethered by one hand to something). (PS I'm female!)